# How to add a &nbsp; in a map-function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, material-ui

Working in React I stumbled across this problem:

```
 <Grid item>
    {
        rolePriorities.map((rp, index) => (
                <Chip key={index} label={rp} color="primary" sx={{ color: "whitesmoke" }} />  &nbsp; //error happens here
        ))
    }
</Grid>
```

This doesn't work as it doesn't compile (Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ",")

I've also tried with a `+`, putting it in parentheses, using the `String` code `String.fromCharCode(160)`, but none of them have worked so far. It compiles with a `<div/>` around it, but I want the chips to be in the same line and not stacked on each other.

Anybody know how I could put a whitespace between the `Array`-items without making them stack?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap it into a Fragment because in this way technically you are trying to return 2 children in one jsx which is not allowed.

```js
 <Grid item>
    {
        rolePriorities.map((rp, index) => (
               <>
                <Chip key={index} label={rp} color="primary" sx={{ color: "whitesmoke" }} />
                &nbsp;
               </>
        ))
    }
</Grid>
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know you could just do that.